# Genetic Algorithm by doing principal component analysis - Reg

Tags: matlab, genetic-algorithm, pca

I want to optimize an optimization problem using genetic algorithm. But the number of variables are large. ( around 1500 to 2000). can i use principal component analysis and reduce the number of variables (inputs) to 20 or 30 and optimize using genetic algorithm in MATLAB. can i get reasonably accurate optimal value.

Answer (score 0):

I think you *should* use PCA to reduce the number of variables. That's way too many for even GA to deal with. And, assuming that PCA will work on your variables, i.e. they have some mutual information rather than all independent, then your solution will converge a lot quicker (it probably would never give a satisfactory result with all those variables unless you have massive numbers of organisms, like billions).